# Clicking on List Item on Dropdown

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, coded-ui-tests

I'm having a problem in interacting with a custom dropdown control. It works fine the 1st 6 times, but after that, since the screen is resized, it could no longer locate and click the option in the dropdown control, returning an exception - can't click on hidden control. I tried putting in a itemField.DrawHighlight(); on the control I'm looking for, and it finds it, however it can't click on it. I also tried a to scroll down, but it seems to be not working.

```
bool addItemCheck = false;
int scrollCheck = 0;
while (Check == false)
{
    var addItem= new HtmlButton(window);
    addItem.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlButton.PropertyNames.Id, "add-new-item");
    Mouse.Click(addItem);

    scrollCheck = scrollCheck + 1;
    if (scrollCheck > 6)
    {
        Mouse.MoveScrollWheel(window, -100);
    }

    var itemDropDown = new HtmlSpan(window);
    itemDropDown .SearchProperties.Add(HtmlSpan.PropertyNames.Class, "item-dropdown");
    itemDropDown .SearchProperties.Add(HtmlSpan.PropertyNames.InnerText, "Select an Item");
    Mouse.Click(itemDropDown );

    addItemCheck = itemDropDown.Exists;
}

bool itemBoxCheck = false;
HtmlCustom itemBox = null;
while (itemBoxCheck == false)
{                                                                             
    itemBox = new HtmlCustom(window);                                         
    itemBox.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlCustom.PropertyNames.Id, "item-listbox");

    var itemField = new HtmlCustom(itemBox);                                  
    itemField .SearchProperties.Add(HtmlCustom.PropertyNames.InnerText, item);
    Mouse.Click(itemField);                                                   

    itemBoxCheck = itemBox.Exists;                                            
}
```

I would really appreciate any help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling the method InsureClickable() on the control before attempting to click on it.

for example:

```
itemDropDown.EnsureClickable();
 Mouse.Click(itemDropDown);
```

### Edit:

if this doesn't work you'll have to scroll down to the item.

try using:

```
 Mouse.MoveScrollWheel()
```

if that doesn't work also you'll have to map the scroll control and click on it.

Comment: Hello, I appreciate the answer @barakcaf. I'm afraid it doesn't work, I tried it with:

`var itemField = new HtmlCustom(itemBox);` 
`itemField.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlCustom.PropertyNames.InnerText, item);`</br>
`itemField.EnsureClickable();`</br>
`Mouse.Click(itemField);`</br>


It does the same behavior and returns the exception. Thank you again for your help.

Comment: Wow, that was sad, how do you linebreak here?

Comment: i've edited the answer - hope it works - don't be shy with the votes:)